# Hash of arrays printing garbage values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to print data from a hash of arrays in a perl program.
But it prints some garbage values along with original data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %Quarter = (
                June => ["06/03/2012", "06/10/2012", "06/17/2012", "06/24/2012"],
                July => ["07/01/2012", "07/08/2012", "07/15/2012", "07/22/2012"],
                August => ["08/05/2012", "08/12/2012", "08/19/2012", "08/26/2012"],
);


foreach my $month ( %Quarter ) {
        print "$month\n";
}
```

output:

```
July
ARRAY(0x9281af8)
June
ARRAY(0x9281bdc)
August
ARRAY(0x929ade8)
```

Any idea what is going wrong in this program.

Thanks

Comment: Your questions both here and in the comments below indicate that you a new to Perl. It may help you to read the [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) book to get a good background in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl a hash can be trivially converted to an array with an equal number of elements. Each even numbered element is a key and the following (odd numbered) element is the corresponding value.

Now, `foreach` is an operator that iterates over arrays, not over hashes. Therefore your code does what it does: the loop variable iterates over a key, a value, the next key, next value etc.

There are several ways in which you can iterate over a hash:

1. Iterate over all key/value pairs. You usually do that with something like `while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) { ... }`
2. Retrieve all keys from a hash and iterate over those: `foreach my $key (keys %hash) { ... }`
3. If you don't need the keys and only the values then you can also tetrieve all values from the hash and iterate over those with `foreach my $value (values %hash) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks..
It works but why is it printing in random order? Any idea!! I want it as June, July, August!! Right now it prints July, June, August

Comment: In Perl hashes do not preserve the order of their keys (unlike PHP for example).

Comment: Is there anyway I can get it in order?

Comment: No. You have to think of a different way of storing your data, or store an additional assignment of month names to their positions in another data structure and sort the keys according to that data structure.

Comment: @Ram no, hashes are by definition (and perhaps for security reasons) unordered: They are a *set* of keys with values attached. If you need to preserve order, you will want to use an array (where each field is an arrayref containing a name-arrayref pair: `([June=>[...]],[July=>[...]],...)`) or apply some sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Others answered the question on how to iterate over the day arrays, but the problem with printing months in the right order is that hashes aren't ordered. I have two possible solutions for this.

The first involves iterating over the month keys manually like this:

```
foreach my $month_name (qw(June July August)) {
    print $month_name . ': ' . join ', ' => @{$Quarter{$month_name}};
}
```

Or you need to provide the data structure as an array of hashes:

```
my @months = (
    {name => 'June', days => ["06/03/2012", "06/10/2012", "06/17/2012", "06/24/2012"]},
    # ...
);

foreach my $month (@months) {
    print $month->{name} . ': ' . join ', ' => @{$month->{days}};
}
```

TIMTOWTDI! Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I'm kinda new here and I hope it's OK to answer to parts of the problem. Please correct me if this was wrong.

Comment: that'll do just fine. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In the foreach loop, $month is a reference to an array, you have to do

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper\%Quarter;
```

or

```
foreach my $month (keys %Quarter ) {
    print "$_\n" for @{$Quarter{$month}};
}
```

Comment: No, That prints:
07/01/2012 07/08/2012 07/15/2012 07/22/2012

06/03/2012 06/10/2012 06/17/2012 06/24/2012

08/05/2012 08/12/2012 08/19/2012 08/26/2012

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you want to print the month names, you need to loop over `keys %Quarter`. If you want keys and values paired up, use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html). If you use a hash in an array context like this, you get all keys *and* all values.

```
foreach my $month ( keys %Quarter ) {
        print "$month\n";
}
```

Comment: And also why is it printing in random order? Any idea!! I want it as June, July, August!!
Right now it prints July, June, August

Answer (score 0):

Your question hasn't been answered - if I'm not wrong.... I'd say, the "garbage" that you're seeing is not the data, but it says what it is, it's anonymous ARRAYs you're assigning to your hash keys.

So taking your code it should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %Quarter = (
            June => ["06/03/2012", "06/10/2012", "06/17/2012", "06/24/2012"],
            July => ["07/01/2012", "07/08/2012", "07/15/2012", "07/22/2012"],
            August => ["08/05/2012", "08/12/2012", "08/19/2012", "08/26/2012"],
);


#foreach my $month ( %Quarter ) {
#    print "$month\n";
#}
while(my ($k,$v) = each %Quarter) {
  foreach my $x (@$v) {
    print $x."\n";
  }
}
```